# how to stop play sound when close the app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I had **interface** which it **play sound** file when **check select input** from **html** file .it worked well but when i added new code to stop sound file when close the app it doesnot work. I added my code at my **activity** class not interface .

activity method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    //Call HTML Files
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    //

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
}
@Override 
public void onDestroy()
{
    mp.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void playsound(String value ) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
  mp.start();
    }
    else 
    {  mp.stop();}
}
```

Note **mp** is instance from **MediaPlayer**

Comment: please provide your all code. mp.stop() will stop your media player instance. But if your playing sound from other resources like .swf or html you have to stop from their itself.

Comment: Put this code in `onPause()`

Comment: the app stopped unexpectedly

Comment: Please post your full activity. This snippet of code is useless.

Comment: try this code   if( mp == null) {
   return;
  }

  if (mp.isPlaying()) {
   mp.stop();
  }

  mp.release();
  mp = null;

Answer (score -2):

I think in that html you opened in a seperate window try shouldoverrideurl method in webview so if you just come out from app it automatically stop your play sound.

Comment: This is wrong. Do not kill your own process. Just stop the playback on `onPause()` or `onStop()` and that's it.